# R - Number of days since last occurrence

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
 id     date
 1001   2012-10-11
 1005   2013-02-20
 1005   2012-11-21
 1005   2014-03-14
 1003   2013-10-25
 1003   2013-11-30
```

I need to find, for each row, the number of days that have passed since the last occurrence of that id. For the above example, the answer would look like this:

```
 id     date        no_of_days
 1001   2012-10-11  NA
 1005   2013-02-20  91
 1005   2012-11-21  NA
 1005   2014-03-14  387
 1003   2013-10-25  NA
 1003   2013-11-30  36
```

A bit of searching got me to the point where I can add a new column with values that were generated by applying a function on subgroups (the R equivalent of STATA's "bysort"):

```
df$no_of_days<-with(df,ave(id,id,FUN=days_passed,na.rm=TRUE))
```

However, defining the new function days_passed is proving to be tricky as I have to find the last occurrence of that uniqid, and then formulate the function accordingly.

I'm new to R, so any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or using `ave` (similar to @David Arenburg's approach)

```
 indx <- with(df, order(id, date))
 df1 <- transform(df[indx,], no_of_days=ave(as.numeric(date), id,
                    FUN= function(x) c(NA, diff(x))))[order(indx),]
 df1     
 #    id       date no_of_days
 #1 1001 2012-10-11         NA
 #2 1005 2013-02-20         91
 #3 1005 2012-11-21         NA
 #4 1005 2014-03-14        387
 #5 1003 2013-10-25         NA
 #6 1003 2013-11-30         36
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1001L, 1005L, 1005L, 1005L, 1003L, 1003L
), date = structure(c(15624, 15756, 15665, 16143, 16003, 16039
), class = "Date")), .Names = c("id", "date"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `data.table` package you could try the following (though it doesn't preserve the order). Assuming `df` is your data set

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df)[, date := as.Date(date)], id, date) # If `date` is already of `Date` class you can skip the `as.Date` part
df[, no_of_days := c(NA, diff(date)) , by = id][]
#      id       date no_of_days
# 1: 1001 2012-10-11         NA
# 2: 1003 2013-10-25         NA
# 3: 1003 2013-11-30         36
# 4: 1005 2012-11-21         NA
# 5: 1005 2013-02-20         91
# 6: 1005 2014-03-14        387
```

Or (as @Arun suggesting) you can preserve the order by using `order` instead of `setkey`

```
setDT(df)[, date := as.Date(date)][order(id, date), 
            no := c(NA, diff(date)), by = id][]
```

---

Could as well try `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  arrange(id, date) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(no_of_days = c(NA, diff(date)))
```

Comment: You can preserve the order by doing: `setDT(df)[, date := as.Date(date)][order(id, date), no := c(NA, diff(date)), by=id][]`